# Api Bundle Symfony set authorization header

Tags: symfony, oauth, authorization

In Symfony 2 I am using this bundle library (https://github.com/LeaseWeb/LswApiCallerBundle) to make API REQUEST.
This is the main function to do it:

```
$output = $this->get('api_caller')->call(new HttpPostJson($url, $parameters));
```

I would like to set an Authentication Header for oAuth 2!

Thanks

Comment: the second argument in the httppostjson() is a object of LeaseWeb/LswApiCallerBundle/Call/CurlCall.php and its constructor is

public function __construct($url,$requestObject,$asAssociativeArray=false)
    {
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->requestObject = $requestObject;
        $this->asAssociativeArray = $asAssociativeArray;
        $this->generateRequestData();
    }

Comment: @abbiya thank you! but where I should put Authorization: $authorization ? in my example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used that library about 1 month ago. I figured it out just customizing the class HttpPostJson.

You should do something like this:

```
in Lsw\ApiCallerBundle\Call

public function makeRequest($curl, $options, $authorization)
{
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->requestData);
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Authorization: ' . $authorization
    ));
    $curl->setoptArray($options);
    $this->responseData = $curl->exec();
}
```

I just added

```
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Authorization: ' . $authorization
    ));
```

in every API Call that needed an authorization.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to write code because the library is already prepared to receive any curl option.

Pass the httpheaders like an associative array as the next example:

```
//it's a fake test
$url = 'http://www.example.com';
$data = array();
$returnAssociativeArray = true;

//add curl options
$options = array(
    'userpwd' => 'demo:privateKey'
    'httpheader' => array('Content-type' => 'application/json')
);


$json = $this->container->get('api_caller')->call(
            new HttpPostJson(
                $url,
                $data,
                $returnAssociativeArray,
                $options
            )
        );
```